# C: Bus Error with Make Capital function

Tags: c

I wrote a function to turn all the letters in a string capital, but for some reason, when I use it in an evidence file, it gives me a "bus error". Can someone explain what that means?

Here's the function

```
void make_capital(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(s) ; i++) {
        if(('a' <= s[i]) && (s[i] <= 'z')) {
            s[i] -= 32;
           }
    }
}
```

and here's how I'm using it in the evidence file

```
char* capital_test = malloc(8);
capital_test = "abCdEfG";
make_capital(capital_test);
printf("%s\n", capital_test);
```

Comment: `strlen()` computes the length on each call, so this `for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(s) ; i++)` is bad.

Comment: To copy a string, you must use `strcpy`. Affectation will only set `capital_test` to point to a constant string, and trying to modify a constant string can have unpredictable (and often fatal) consequences.

Comment: @kuroineko: "Affectation"? Is than an autocorrect of "Assignment"?

Comment: @KeithThompson excuse my French

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
capital_test = "abCdEfG";
```

if you print the address that `capital_test` points to after `malloc()` and before this assignment you will notice it changed.

You are modifying a string literal, and that causes undefined behavior, when you do the assignment above, unlike many other languages in c you don't modify the content the poitner points too, you instead make the pointer point to the string literal.

Then you pass that poitner to the function, and instead of modifying the newly allocated memory you modify the string literal.

You should copy the contents of the string, you could write a loop and copy each character or you can use the standard function `strcpy()`, though this function requires the inclusion of the `string.h` header.

So to fix the problem you should

```
char *capital_test = malloc(8);
if (capital_test == NULL)
    return -1; /* allocation error, you can't continue */
strcpy(capital_test, "abCdEfG");
```

Also, the for loop could be written without using `strlen()` because you are going to iterate through all the characters in the string, so this

```
for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
```

would do the same, without using `strlen()` on each iteration.

And finally you can use the `toupper()` function from `ctype.h`, so your loop would be simply

```
for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
```

**One more thing**: when you use `malloc()` you must use `free()` if this code is intended for a demonstration only or you don't need the string outside of the current function, you can use an array instead of a pointer, since when you pass the array to the function it will behave exactly as the pointer does and it's as simple as

```
char capital_test[] = "abCdEfG";
```

this will initialize `capital_test` to the string and including the `nul` termination byte, so you will be safe if you try to change it because it's not a pointer to a string literal but an array instead.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why?

Comment: Do you do this so that you will have the first answer?